# Use IF condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a date column in my table. I want to get all the records where the number of months compared to today's date is greater than 10, but I want to apply this condition only if my declared parameter has value `@parameter='Apply'`. Otherwise, I do not want to enforce the date criteria.

My results should be the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd rows when `@parameter ='Apply'`, else if `@parameter` is something else, then all four rows would be returned.

```
  GetDate         Val
------------     -----
 1/12/2013         A
 1/12/2012         B
 1/12/2014         C
 1/12/2015         D
```

The following works as expected, but with lots of redundant  code. Is there way to put the if condition in the where clause ?

```
DECLARE @parameter VARCHAR(10)='Apply'
if(@parameter='Apply')
begin
select * from testTable where
    DATEDIFF(MONTH,GetDate,GETDATE()) >10
end
else
begin
    select * from testTable
end
```

Comment: Relevant: [Catch-all Queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Answer (score 3):

This will do the same thing:

```
select * 
from testTable 
where (DATEDIFF(MONTH,GetDate,GETDATE()) >10 AND @parameter='Apply')
OR @parameter <> 'Apply'
```

Comment: This will have the same output, but is SQL server smart enough to optimize this in a way that makes sense?